# I am trying to Load html string into a webview. But the webview shows a white blank colour on run time

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to Load html string into a webview. But the webview shows a white blank colour on run time. added the UIWebViewDelegate and declare object like this.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *aboutWebView;
```

but still having the same issue.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [_aboutWebView setDelegate:self];

    [self loadWebView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(void)loadWebView{
    _aboutWebView= [[UIWebView alloc]init];
    _aboutWebView.backgroundColor= [UIColor blueColor];
    NSString *embedHTML= @"html Code";

    [_aboutWebView loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];

}
```

Comment: I tried your same code it works for me.Don't allocate and init the _aboutWebView in loadWebView method.

Comment: thanks ! that was the issue @user3182143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the below line from your code.It works for you.

```
_aboutWebView= [[UIWebView alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the web-view delegate after initialising it , and add this line of code `[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for allocating your webview again in loadWebView method of yours.
comment this line "_aboutWebView= [[UIWebView alloc]init]".

You are already creating an IBOutlet for your webview which automatically creates an object for view.

Answer (score 0):

Have below in HTML String

```
<head><style type='text/css'>body {background-color: transparent;border: 0px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}</style></head>
```

And for webview have this

```
yourWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
yourWebView.opaque = NO;
```

This will not show white color in run time...

Answer (score 0):

First at all,your HTML format is not correct,writing correct HTML to load on webView.
Then,add self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; in function - (void)viewDidLoad.

Hope to help you！